# executing single line commands with erl executable?

Tags: shell, erlang

I would like to run a few small Erlang functions from the command line.

For example to print the date in python, I could use:

```
python -c 'import time; print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))'
```

I was hoping to be able to similar for Erlang:

```
erl -s 'date().'
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{'date().',start,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Is it possible to run small Erlang scripts from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run small Erlang programs from the command line using the `eval` option. For example:

```
erl -noinput -eval 'io:format("hello world~n").' -s init stop
```

You can read [the `erl` man page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) for more details on command-line options, but briefly:

- `-noinput` means there's nothing for the runtime to read
- `-eval` treats its argument as Erlang code text to evaluate and execute
- `-s init stop` executes [the `init:stop/0` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/init.html#stop-0) to shut down the runtime

To print the current date and time, you can take a similar approach:

```
erl -noinput -eval '{{Y,Mo,D},{H,Mi,S}} = calendar:now_to_local_time(os:timestamp()),
  io:format("~4.4w-~2.2.0w-~2.2.0w ~2.2.0w:~2.2.0w:~2.2.0w~n",[Y,Mo,D,H,Mi,S]).' -s init stop
```

This code retrieves the current time using `os:timestamp/0`, converts it to local time via `calendar:now_to_local_time/1`, and then formats that result using `io:format/2`, producing a result like this:

```
2014-10-22 10:09:53
```